# How to get Opportunityproduct by QuoteDetail in MS Dynamics CRM?

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am a newbie in the MS Dynamics CRM plugin-development and I have to develop a plugin that change the businnes logic of CRM.

I have the QuoteDetail-entity and I want to find the OppoptunityProduct from which this QuoteDetail was generated.

Is it possible? I have not found any possibility to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question in other community and get correct answer: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/120310.aspx

I have used this tool: http://crm2011entitymaps.codeplex.com/ 
I created a new attribute on opportunity & quote product and then assigned it some sort of unique identifier as record was created. After it I have created a mapping for the custom value between the product lines.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to traverse the relationship between the Quote and Opportunity itself, so the relationship will be something like OpportunityProduct -> Opportunity -> Quote -> QuoteProduct, ensuring that the OpportunityProduct and QuoteProduct are using the same Product entity (or if it is a Write-In Product, make sure that they have the same description).  All of this will be possible using LINQ statements to extract the relevant records.